# ScriptDb usage from WebApp

Tags: google-apps-script

When using `ScriptDb` from within a WebApp that can be accessed by anyone and runs as the accessing user together with `Triggers` from within that WebApp it seems as if the user can not be correctly determined.

1. Google Apps Script as `WebApp` for `Anyone` running `as the accessing user`
2. `ScriptApp.newTrigger("myfunc").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();`

Where function `myfunc` is:

```
var q = {
  user: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
};
result = db.query(q).sortBy('when', db.ASCENDING);
```

`result` seems to be empty when `myfunc` is being accessed from the trigger.

Shouldn't the active user within the trigger be the one that installed it? E.g. the user accessing the WebApp when first giving the authorization?

Comment: Try to use "Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();" instead of `getActiveUser`

Comment: Nice catch @megabyte1024, you probably should "promote" that comment into an answer.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu, thank you. Unfortunately I had not time to check it if it works in real code. Just recalled that there is a function which return "effective" user. I will check if it work in real code ASAP and if it works will publish it as an answer.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu. An answer is published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Session.getEffectiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_session#getEffectiveUser) method returns the correct user email, as expected. Since when the script is running from a trigger, there's no one "active" using it. The "effective" user though is always set, as it is the account which the script is running "under". Here is a sample web application which emails an expected email address in the subject and body.

```
function doGet() {
  var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("testTrigger").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel("test"));
  return app;
}

function testTrigger(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail("xxx@sample.com", "Subject: " + Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "Body: " + Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer and explain the difference between effective and active users. Again, nice catch!

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu, not a problem at all. When readers have more information from an answer is better.